# Garbage at the end of vector<char> c++

Tags: c++

I have an interesting problem. After initializing my vector, I see there is some garbage after the data. Here is what my debugger shows:

[image: Garbage at end of vector data]

Here is how I initialize my vector:

```
std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1'};
```

The problem occurs when I try to use `responsebuf.data()` to output the buffer's contents:

```
std::cout << responsebuf.data();
```

How can I output the data without getting these garbage bytes too?

Comment: This is fine.  The size is `1`, so you can ignore garbage after the `1`.

Comment: You _don't_ have garbage. The vector is initialized with a size of 1. It might have a larger _capacity_ and that memory is not initialized. Attempting to access more data than the vector's size via the pointer that `data()` returns is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, but I need to use .data(). And then this garbage is shown

Comment: Why are you using `data`? Are you expecting it to give you a NUL-terminated string? If so, the vector needs to contain that character too. Otherwise consider something like `std::string_view`. When you have a specific problem, you should provide code to demonstrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: I`m using .data() because I want to output this vector in console via cout.

Comment: Then _you_ need to null-terminate it.

Comment: `std::cout << std::string_view(responsebuf.data(), responsebuf.size());`

Comment: Ok, null-terminating is work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Taking a (small) step back: since you apparently want to use it like a string, is there a good reason you can't just use `std::string`? `std::string responsebuf = '1'; std::cout << responsebuf;`

Comment: `std::string` also has [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) for compatibility this way if necessary, but it normally isn't as you can just `std::cout << s`.

Comment: FWIW, I recognise that 'garbage'.  It's a 4 byte sentinel that MSVC puts on the end of heap allocations in debug builds to detect overruns.  Just so you know,

Comment: A `vector<char>` is not null terminated. Streaming it's `data()` selects an `operator<<()` that ASSUMES it is provided with a null-terminated array, so your code has undefined behaviour.  Either add a terminator to the vector (a last element with value `'\0'`) or print characters individually in a loop.  You can also convert to a `std::string`  (e.g.  `std::string output(responsebuf.begin(), responsebuf.end());`) since the `operator<<()` for a `string` will output it correctly.  Bear in mind that, before C++11, `std::string::data()` was also NOT required to be nul terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector may or may not have allocated additional memory past its initial size. Either way, you are not allowed to access that memory. Doing so is undefined behavior. It's not so much "garbage" existing there in memory, but more like "none of your program's business".

Since you are apparently expecting your vector's contents to behave like NUL-terminated string, you have a few options:

1. Explicitly terminate on construction:

   ```
   std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1', '\0'};
   std::cout << responsebuf.data();
   ```
2. Append a NUL character later:

   ```
   std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1'};
   responsebuf.push_back('\0');
   std::cout << responsebuf.data();
   ```
3. Use [string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

   ```
   std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1'};
   std::cout << std::string_view(responsebuf.data(), responsebuf.size());
   ```
4. Use [ostream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

   ```
   std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1'};
   std::copy(responsebuf.begin(),
             responsebuf.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
   ```
5. Overload the formatted output operator:

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const std::vector<char>& v)
   {
       for (char c : v) s << c;
       return s;
   }

   //...
   std::vector<char> responsebuf {'1'};
   std::cout << responsebuf;
   ```

Note that if your buffer actually contains embedded NUL bytes as part of its data, then be aware that these various techniques may produce different output.

Comment: Another option is to use `cout.write()`, eg: `std::cout.write(responsebuf.data(), responsebuf.size());`

Comment: I vote for option 3. Use a string_view for printing.

Comment: Yes, my preferred option also. This is basically the exact kind of thing that `string_view` is designed for. I wish we didn't have to wait until C++17 to get it! But at least Boost has one.